# PL/SQL invalidation

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have scenario where a JDBC session is referencing a PL/SQL package. When I change the package body and recompile it, the session does not throw any exception but when I recompile the package specification it throws the following exception. My question is why the session does not throw any exception when package body changes, if I make changes in the package body, will the existing session see the changes?

```
ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
```

Answer (score 0):

If a PL/SQL package has global variables (constant or modifiable), then the package is considered to have state. If you change the package, the variables are reinitialized and the state is lost.

If a database session has used the package, it will get an ORA-04068 exception when it access the package the next time. If it handles the exception, it can then continue to use the package without receiving the exception again. Of course, the state is lost and the new version of the package applies.

For PL/SQL packages without global variables, no error is thrown. The new version of the package immediately applies to all sessions.

So why do you expect the session to throw an exception if the changed package is no longer used in that session? That would cause more problems than add value.

Comment: Constants don't cause this [from 11.2.0.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/whatsnew.htm). That 'new features' section also links to the docs for package state.

Comment: You say For PL/SQL packages without global variables, no error is thrown. The new version of the package immediately applies to all sessions. It's not true. For that you have to change the state of the package as PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE

Answer (score 0):

Read the sections "**Easier Application Design**" and "**Hidden Implementation Details**" in  [Reasons to use Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17622/packages.htm#i2408)

And above all the documentation in the section "**Package Writing Guidelines**" (same page) states explicitly:

> In package specifications, declare only items that must be visible to
>   invoking programs.
>
> This practice prevents other developers from building unsafe
>   dependencies on your implementation details and reduces the need for
>   recompilation.
>
> If you change the package specification, you must recompile any
>   subprograms that invoke the public subprograms of the package. If you
>   change only the package body, you need not recompile those
>   subprograms.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known issue.
Here you can find any detail from how to solve it.
http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2010/12/how-to-solve-ora-4068.html.

But if you to be very careful with global variable! If they are used in your package, then don't compile your package when other program are using it.

From dba point of view, it's possible to know who have a "lock" on this package via v$access view. So you can raise compilation via trigger on ddl.